# Mouse bugueado virtual box

Tags: virtualbox

estoy usando virtual box para probar win 10, cuando inicio la maquina esta todo bien pero cuando ya estoy en el escritorio el mouse se me bugea y es demasiado molesto y no he encontrado nada de como solucionarlo.

así se ve el mouse con esa linea negra que lo sigue a todos lados

[image: asi se ve el mouse]

Comment: Instalaste los guest additions en la VM?

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque no parece ajustarse a [ask]

Comment: @BetaM no puedo poner código por que virtual box no es un lenguaje de programación, tampoco puedo pasarles mi maquina virtual por no la van a descargar,  entonces no se a que te refieres con que no se ajusta ? no todo es programación.

Comment: stackoverflow es una biblioteca de preguntas y respuestas y es curioso que mi pregunta la quieras cerrar y esta que esta toda en [ingles](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/423091/starting-error-of-virtual-machine) todavía siga abierta, si virtualbox no va con la temática de la pagina deberían eliminar la etiqueta.

Comment: @HelloWorld solo trato de guiarte, tienes razón, ahora esta cerrada por estar escrita en otro idioma distinto al de la plataforma, yo finalizo aqui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instala las Guest Additions, está en Dispositivos y la última opción. En Windows se te abrirá el instalador y tendrás que reiniciar, con ellas instaladas podrás redimensionar la pantalla[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: no aparecenada cuando le doy ahí

Comment: si funciona había que esperar un poco mas.